# webform block in a page template , inside a colorbox - validation does not show

Tags: webforms, forms

I created a page tpl for a view where using colorbox inline i`m displacing a webform block and some additional text.

My problem is that the error messages are not showing. The submission is working but the messages are not shown.

Here is a part of my code inside a view.tpl

```
            <div class='modal' style='display:none'>
                <div id='inline_content_contact' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
                   <?php  print $content; ?>

                   <?php
                       $block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-15');
                       print render($block['content']);
                   ?>

                </div>
            </div>
```

I activated the webform ajax and no redirect after in order to stay in colorbox after submission.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are printed in $messages on a normal page, have you tried adding that? 
[image]

Comment: yes i just added print $messages; right before module_invoke
but is still the same , i also get Notice: Undefined variable: messages in include().

Comment: i moved the form block in view(not in a colorbox) and the error messages are shown.

Only in colorbox are not.

My theme is bootstrap if it counts